# How can I add my new facebook app to my fan page?

Tags: facebook, favorite

I created an app on facebook, and it works it's at https://apps.facebook.com/bills-wheels-youtube/

it shows up in my apps at the app center.

When I go to add it to my favorites tab it doesn't show up

I've added a app before and it worked with no problems. Did they change how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'favorites tab'?

Comment: If you go to edit page > update info > apps, do you see the app in there? If so, it should appear on your page if there are no additional settings within the app that affect the display.